# How to serialize a typeof model in c#

Tags: entity-framework, serialization, asp.net-mvc-4, xml-serialization

I want to serialize an EF model like this

```
TableA theObject = db.TableA.find(uid);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TableA));
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(directory, filename));
serializer.Serialize(writer, theObject);
writer.Close();
```

But the code breaks and it says it cannot serialize the member because its an interface. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no ways to serialize an interface, thus the only way that I can do was, create a translation class for the EF object that I wanted to serialize

For collection members I used arrays like this

```
public class QueryModelTemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ParameterModelTemplate[] Parameters;
}
```